# Send IP address from frontend using ReactJS to server NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, ip, client

At present I am using `WEBRTC` for getting IP address from client side.

But I have issues with browsers like Internet Explorer etc.
I don't want to hit other third party servers for getting IP.

Is there a way to get IP address from ReactJS without hitting third party servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a request to your own nodejs server and reply with the IP address. that way 3rd party servers wont be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Check sample express code below and use

```
app.get('/getIP', getClientIP);
```

[Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/serifcetiner/tgcbbykh/)